# Why does inserting a new row for a table in Excel mess up the colors/symmetry in the subsequent rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table with many rows and columns in excel. When I add a new row within the table (left click, insert, row above), the subsequent rows get thrown off with their banded colors in a seemingly random manner. How do I insert a new row at any point in the table and keep the following rows symmetrical?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... Could you add a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: How did you construct the table and specify the banding?

Comment: Check to see if there is conditional formatting in the table range. It could be fill color based on row number that's odd or even.

Comment: Copy and Paste keep source formatting? Then delete all values..